# Extract Data between Strings or Tags

Tags: php

Please note: I am fairly new to using php commands and regex.
I have a html document retrieved through php commands, now I want to extract the  data from html between two strings.

For example:

```
**<h4 class=3D"style1"> HIGH (blah)</h4>**
<h4><br>
<br></b>
 <br>
&nbsp;</h4>
<TR>
 <TD width=3D"513">
<B**>**textttttttttt**</**B><br><br><br><br><hr><table><tr><td>=
<b>texttttt<br><br><br><br>textttttttt<table>ttttttttttttt</table>ttttttttttttt
</table></td></tr></table> 
<TD width=3D"513">
<ul>
= 
=
</u1>                              
**<p align=3D"right"><b>REGISTRAR(EVALUATION)<=
/b></p>**
```

I need the text between the strings "**HIGH**" and "**REGISTRAR**". Mainly, I needed the data from the tags `<TD width=3D"513">` and `<TD width=3D"513">`,but there are many instances where this tag occurs.

Comment: **YOU DO NOT WANT REGEX FOR THAT**

Comment: POSSIBLE DUPLICATE OF [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Please use normal language - there's no need to shout in here.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole code was contained in **$code**, I would do the following.

```
$beginning = 'HIGH';
$ending    = 'REGISTRAR';
if (false !== $left = strpos($code, $beginning))
{
    $left   += strlen($beginning);
    $extract = (false === $right = strpos($code, $ending, $left)?
        $extract = substr($code, $left, $right - $left): '';
}
echo (isset($extract))?
    "The code chunk was extracted and it is:\n$extract\n":
    "The code chunk was not found. :(\n";
```

So, **$extract** would end up containing the text you wanted to ...extract.

Greetings~

(**Note:** I wrote this code on the fly and did not even try it, if there is any error I am sorry and please let me know)